# Regex in C# to split string by char which can be escaped

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem, I a have a string which looks like this:

```
abc'def'ghi?'jkl'mno?'pqr'stu'vwx'yz'
```

I need to split this string by the ' char, but only if no question mark stand in front of it, which escape the ' char. And as an addition to this, if the ' is escaped I need the result string without the question mark char.

The result should be for this example a List:

```
abc
def
ghi'jkl
mno'pqr
stu
vwx
yz
```

I hope you can help me on this one

Kind regards

Comment: Regex questions are not an excuse to not show what you have tried

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I have no clue about regex.
I faced the problems moments ago, because this string is coming from the customer and until now I splitted only by String.split because I don't know that they do escaping, because on all examples send so far there were no escapings.

Comment: Ok, have you tried solving the problem without a regular expression? I can easily be done. In C#, I believe it is three method calls to accomplish what you want. (If you mandate that we use a regex, I suspect this is a homework problem.)

Comment: Why not split the string into a string array, and then with a loop go trough all elements of the array to check for the question mark. Save the elements that do not have the question mark into a 2nd array. And do nothing with the ones that contain question marks. (thus, simply use string.split and string.contains in a loop function).

Comment: This string is coming from a file and I until now I do File.ReadAllText and then split by ' worked fine until now :)

Comment: You could probably do it in 2 replaces - Replace `?'` with something, Split on `'` then replace all the first replace string with `'` again. Otherwise it looks like a good excuse to learn regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] output=Regex.Split(input,@"(?<!\?)'")
                     .Select(x=>x.Replace("?'","'"))
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: So, I will try this one, but there is one problem I forgot to mention, the chars ' and ? are dynamicly, they can be any char (no string!).
I know that RegEx have special chars that need escaping on there own.
Can you modify your Code a bit to insure that if for example for escaping a RegEx special char is used that this will be handled correct.

Comment: Finally right answer. `+1` for that. Just a tip, this creates an extra empty string at the end of output array (`output[7]` will be empty string) `;)`

Comment: @SharpNoiZy use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to escape characters

Comment: @Anirudh Around the complete regex string or only the dynamicly inserted chars in the regex?

Comment: @SharpNoiZy only dynamically inserted chars

Comment: @Anirudh Sorry, but I don't get it ;(

Regex.Split(content, @"(" + Regex.Escape(adviseSegment.ReleaseIndicator.ToString()) + "<!" + Regex.Escape(adviseSegment.ReleaseIndicator.ToString()) + ")" + Regex.Escape(adviseSegment.SegmentTerminator.ToString())).Select(x => x.Replace("?'", "'")).ToList();

ReleaseIndicator is in the example the ? char and SegmentTerminator is the ' char. But this line of code return only one line while your static method works perfect and return 30000 lines.

Comment: @SharpNoiZy it should be `"(?<!"
+Regex.Escape(ReleaseIndicator)+")"
+Regex.Escape(SegmentTerminator);`

Answer (score 0):

First check either string contain question mark replace it with null and then split your string as shown below.

```
string value = "abc'def'ghi?'jkl'mno?'pqr'stu'vwx'yz'";

if ( value.Contains("?"))
{
     value = value.Replace("?", null);
}

string[] splitedString = value.Split('\'');
```

Comment: if it doesn't contain it then there isn't anything to replace anyway so its a waste of a check. I also think this is wrong as this will still split `mno'pqr` I believe

Comment: Your answer doesn't get output what OP wants..

Comment: The comments are right, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = "abc'def'ghi?'jkl'mno?'pqr'stu'vwx'yz'";

if ( value.Contains("?"))
{
     value = value.Replace("?", "");
}
value=value.Replace("'",Environment.NewLine);
```

[image]

Comment: Who said we were generating a web page? ;)  `Environment.NewLine` will work for other output.

Comment: Same like the answer from Muhammad Umar, doesn't work

Comment: Who said its not working.Give break point and test the value..For additional information i will update the image..

Comment: Take a look at the expected output, even your own screenshot shows it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use a step by step way like this:

```
string str = @"abc'def'ghi?'jkl'mno?'pqr'stu'vwx'yz'";
string[] results = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<!\?)'");
var regex = new Regex(@"\?(?=')");
foreach (string result in results)
{
    string output = regex.Replace(result, "");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```